# Pycharm doesn't show framework select while making new project

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pycharm

I want to create new project with Pycharm on Ubuntu, but i see only this:

[image: My "New project" window]

Where i don't see framework select part, instead of something like this:
[image: Proper window]

Im using PyCharm edu but I tried it on normal version and it doesn't work as well :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jetbrains only provide those features on Pycharm Professional edition. You won't get it on Edu or Community edition.